# Finding the number of appearances that a number turns up in a certain list of numbers

Tags: performance-tuning, filtering, list-manipulation, code-review, code-request

I have the following code:

```
max = 4000; 
Clear[cnt]; 
cnt[_] = 0; 
Do[
    b = Binomial[n , k]; 
    If[b <= max, cnt[b] += 1], 
    {n, 0, max}, 
    {k, 1, n - 1}
]; 
sel = Select[
    Table[{b, cnt[b]}, {b, 1, max}], 
    #[[2]] >= 1 &
];
a[n_] := Select[
    sel, 
    #[[2]] >= n
][[1, 1]]; 
Quiet@Array[a, 10^3] /. {}[[1, 1]] -> Nothing
```

The code is finding the number of appearances that a number turns up in a certain list of numbers. Is there a way to speed up this calculation, because it takes a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[groupedByCounts]

groupedByCounts[max_] := GroupBy[
    Tally[Join @@ Map[Select[# <= max &]]@
       Join[Table[Binomial[n, Range[n - 1]], {n, 0, Ceiling[(3 + Sqrt[1 + 8 max])/2]}], 
        ConstantArray[Range[1 + Ceiling[(3 + Sqrt[1 + 8 max])/2], max], 2]]], 
    Last -> First]
```

***Examples:***

```
groupedByCounts[100]
```

> ```
> <|1 -> {2}, 
>  2 -> {3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 
>      25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44,
>      46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 
>      64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83,
>      85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100}, 
> 3 -> {6, 20, 70}, 
> 4 -> {10, 15, 21, 35, 28, 56, 36, 84, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91}|>
> ```

```
Short/ @ groupedByCounts[1000]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
groupedByCounts[4000] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.015644
> ```

```
Short /@ groupedByCounts[4000]
```

[image]

```
Keys @ groupedByCounts[4000]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8}
> ```

```
Length /@ groupedByCounts[4000]
```

> ```
> <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 3871, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 117, 6 -> 3, 8 -> 1|>
> ```

```
Keys @ groupedByCounts[10^6]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8}
> ```

```
Length /@ groupedByCounts[10^6]
```

> ```
> <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 998266, 3 -> 10, 4 -> 1715, 6 -> 6, 8 -> 1|>
> ```

You can define your function `a` using `groupedByCounts[4000]`:

```
ClearAll[a]
a[n_] := Join @@ KeySelect[# >= n &]@groupedByCounts[4000]

{#, a @ #} & /@ {3, 4, 5, 6} // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a little mistake in my question (I edited it now), but I need `Binomial[n+2 , k+1]` to be `Binomial[n , k]`.

Comment: Can you help me with editing your code?

Comment: @Jan, please see the updated version.

Comment: thank you very very much! When I tried to calculate groupByCounts[10^9] it takes again long, is there a way to speed your code and calculation up? Thank you again

Comment: is there a way you know about to speed of up?

Comment: @Jan, I will update if I find a faster way.

Comment: Nice, I am looking forward to it if you can find a way!